# How to replace period characters with newline characters in vi?

Tags: regex, vi

I am trying to replace period (.) from a paragraph in vi by new line character.
I tried using

```
:%s/./\r/g
```

But, it removes all the lines and replaces with new lines.

Comment: The problem is that the dot character is a wildcard for **any** character in regex. Try escaping it with \, i.e. using `:%s/\./\r/g` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above method of using only . (period) replaces number of characters present in the file by that many new lines i.e. if I have "h." in my file, then it will replace these two characters by two new lines. Thus, you will have three new lines in this case. (.) means current character in this case.

To replace period (.) by new line, use escape sequences as given below.

:%s/./\r/g

Comment: SO is escaping your backslash before the dot - and I can't edit your post, because I need at least 6 additional characters to do so :/. You can either use a double backslash, put everything between \` oder indent it by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As the . (dot) character is used in regexps and means 'everything' you should escape it to replace the end of lines.
before:

ipsum dolor sit amet. aham. not!.

after -> :%s@\.@\r@g

ipsum dolor sit amet
 aham
 not!

I've just exchanged / by @ just to let it simple to view. % is used to change all of the text, if you need only a region, use 'V' to fist select the region.

Comment: SO is escaping your backslash before the dot - and I can't edit your post, because I need at least 6 additional characters to do so :/. You can either use a double backslash, put everything between \` oder indent it by four spaces.

Comment: And, my personal opinion: you shouldn't use `@` instead of `\` in this case. `/` isn't used anywhere in the sequence, and it's the default character.

Comment: stuXnet, I've used @ just for clear the \\ that should be used. AFAIK you can use anything that's not used on the string you're using inside the command. But it's ok as // is the default. BTW thanks for you comment.